# How to save array from XMLHTTPREQUEST API POST to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, xmlhttprequest

I want to save my Array in Database where send from Javascript XMLHTTP Request.

**Javascript**

```
function xml2() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));   
     }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/sekai_adminlte3_rnd/api/rnd/postdata", true);
    var singlevar = {"country_name":"Indonesia","country_code":"ID"}
    xhttp.send(singlevar);    
  }
```

**Controller in laravel**

```
public function postdata(Request $request)
{
    
    $country = Country::create([

        'country_code' => $request->get('country_code'),
        'country_name' => $request->get('country_name'),

    ]);

    return $country;

}
```

With this code I can't save to database.

Comment: Please show us the error you are receiving.

Comment: You are just missing to add: 

`$country->save()`
and it will work

Comment: I didnt revceive any error, i just cant save the array to database :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the docs:** *"You may also use the `create()` method to save a new model in a single line."*

You are using the `create()` method a bit wrong way because: *"once we have made the attributes mass assignable, we can use the create method to insert a new record in the database."*

So either use the `$country->save();` method instead of `return $country` as you had it in your code **or** better, make the fields **fillable** (mass assignable) in your **Country Model** like:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['country_code', 'country_name'];
}
```

And then in your **Controller** you can use:

```
public function postdata(Request $request)
{        
    $country = Country::create([

        'country_code' => $request->get('country_code'),
        'country_name' => $request->get('country_name'),

    ]);

    // return $country; // this one is not needed at all    
}
```

The `create()` method returns the saved model instance:

Link to the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

**Now, looking at your code a little more,** it is absolutely impossible that you do not have errors (in your browser console) since I do not see any **CSRF token** sent with your request and also the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` method will not pass your data to your Laravel controller as you tried since the data has to be in particular formats.

So make sure that you have CSRF token. The easiest is including that in your `html head` like:

```
<head>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

Then the **token** has to be included in the Javascript script too. You will find it in the script below.

And since your data that you want to send looks like an associative array of data thus it should be included in a **FormData** object (as an appropriate format for the `send()` method) and this way you will not have problems with the data format and getting the data in your controller. So it will work as it is. Your script should look like the following:

```
<script>

function xml2() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    xhttp.open("POST", "/sekai_adminlte3_rnd/api/rnd/postdata", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    
    var singlevar = new FormData;
    singlevar.append('country_name', 'Indonesia');
    singlevar.append('country_code', 'ID');
    xhttp.send(singlevar);
}

</script>
```

I hope you can make it work with the above improvements. If your Routing and Urls are OK it must work.

Comment: Thank's For Your Answer  

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
try{
   $country = new Country();
   $country->country_code = $request->get('country_code'); 
   $country->country_name = $request->get('country_name');
   $country->save();
}
catch(\Exception $e){
   dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your Answer, but its not work from me , are you have the other way ?